# Bigquery Counting totals of occurrences from 2 conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```sql
SELECT 
  member_name as Name, 
  COUNTIF(software_recommendation = "New Unit") AS Recommended, 
  COUNTIF(software_resolution = "New Unit") AS Resolution, 
  ROUND(
    COUNTIF(software_resolution = "New Unit")) / ROUND(COUNTIF(software_recommendation = "New Unit")) as Compliance_Score
FROM `data` w 
LEFT JOIN `members` e 
  ON (w.member_id = e.MID),
unnest(software) software

WHERE 
  MMID = 92812 AND Date BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE()-3, month) 
  AND current_date()-3 
  AND software_resolution = "New Unit"

group by member_name

ORDER BY Name ASC
```

The above is working for me. So I am counting the amount of times a team member, when running our software gets a recommendation to create a New Unit. Then How many times the member actually used the recommendation and not another solution. Lastly, I am calculating the % of how times they were compliant to the recommendation.

Now, what I want trying to do is to count the amount of times the Software recommended anything else apart from a New Unit, but then the member actually provides a new unit as resolution. So the idea is to count both of those conditions as the total of the times that it happened.

I have tried this:

```sql
COUNTIF(software_recommendation != "New Unit" AND software_resolution = "New Unit") AS Upsales
```

but does not achieve what I am trying to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sum(IF(software_recommendation != "New Unit" AND software_resolution = "New Unit", 1, 0)) AS Upsales
```

Also, unnesting like this can produce duplicate rows (not sure if it's impacting your results):

```
, unnest(software) software
```

Comment: Hi Pmo, thank you. I tried that but I get nothing. If I change the 1,0 to 0,1 it gives results, but it is giving me the total of software_recommendation and not counting the cases where the software is not recommending "New Units" but the user ended up giving one as a resolution. I am not sure what those numbers are or do, but I tried doing that just in case.  Thank you for your help.

Oh really? No duplicates right now but good to know. I am not really sure what it does, but it was the only way to get queries to show data from our database. It is a MASSIVE nested table, and I am very new :(

Comment: Apparently something was blocking your way of calculating what I wanted, and apparently so the way I was trying. So it the end your suggestion worked :) after several attempts, it was just a condition on my query blocking the results :

WHERE MMID = 92812 AND Date BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE()-3, month) AND current_date()-3 AND software_resolution = "New Unit"

So I just did a few changed, added a few things and somehow I have made it worked. Thank you